# WooCommerce OAuth 1.0 + JWT authentication with JS/React

Tags: authentication, oauth

My scenario:

- JWT auth for user queries, which requires to customize `.htaccess` to recognize the `Bearer` Authorization header
- OAuth 1.0a for system queries, and because of `.htaccess` customization the auth parameters need to go into the body/query string

I use React for the frontend, WP/WooCommerce as backend. I use `axios` (I'd like to avoid replacing it for lower-level alternatives) and for OAuth 1.0 I use `oauth-1.0a`.

Now GET requests work fine when the oauth parameters are in the querystring, but I just can't get POST to work **in JS** and it's driving me nuts.. However, it does work in Postman when the auth parameters go into the POST body, so I know it's not a server issue. I have zero idea what's not working here. Oauth is not the nicest to debug.

Below is a fully working example, if someone would be so nice to take a look at this. I even threw in a temporary `consumer_key` and `consumer_secret` with `read/write` privileges. It's purely dev right now with sample stuff in WooCommerce, can't destroy much at this point. I'll disable the tokens very soon though.

```
import axios from 'axios'
import OAuth from 'oauth-1.0a'
import crypto from 'crypto-browserify'

const woocommerce = WooCommerceAPI('ck_1da6169c0338088f3e02097a6c9017e800c58176', 'cs_0e090b0a578f48aa8d1096bcd5525415a856836e')
woocommerce
  .post(
    '/customers',
    {username: 'test', 'password': 'test', email: 'test@bullocks.com'}
  ).then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
  }).catch( (error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })

class WooCommerceAPI {
  constructor(consumerKey, consumerSecret, timeout = 60000) {
    this.consumerKey = consumerKey
    this.consumerSecret = consumerSecret
    this.timeout = timeout

    this._request = axios.create({
      baseURL: 'https://boundlessmaps.gis-ops.com' + '/wp-json/wc/v3',
      timeout: this.timeout
    })
  }

  _getOAuth() {
    const data = {
      consumer: {
        key: this.consumerKey,
        secret: this.consumerSecret
      },
      signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
      hash_function: (base_string, key) => {
        return crypto
          .createHmac('sha1', key)
          .update(base_string)
          .digest('base64')
      }
    }

    return new OAuth(data)
  }

  // POST responds with 'Sorry, you are not allowed to create resources.'

  post(endpoint, data_params, params = null) {
    const method = 'POST'

    const oauth_params = this._getOAuth().authorize({
      url: 'https://boundlessmaps.gis-ops.com' + '/wp-json/wc/v3' + endpoint,
      method: method,
      data: data_params
    })

    return this._request.post(endpoint, oauth_params)
  }

  // GET requests work

  static _normalizeQueryString(params) {
    if (!params) {
      return ''
    }

    let queryString = ''
    const params_list = []

    for (const p in params) {
      params_list.push(p)
    }
    params_list.sort()

    for (const i in params_list) {
      if (queryString.length) {
        queryString += '&'
      }

      queryString += encodeURIComponent(params_list[i])
        .replace('%5B', '[')
        .replace('%5D', ']')
      queryString += '='
      queryString += encodeURIComponent(params[params_list[i]])
    }

    return '?' + queryString
  }

  get(endpoint, params = null) {
    const method = 'GET'
    const queryString = WooCommerceAPI._normalizeQueryString(params)

    this._request.interceptors.request.use(config => {
      console.log(queryString)
      return config
    })

    const oauth_params = this._getOAuth().authorize({
      url:
        'https://boundlessmaps.gis-ops.com' +
        '/wp-json/wc/v3' +
        endpoint +
        queryString,
      method: method
    })

    return this._request.get(endpoint, {
      params: { ...params, ...oauth_params }
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puuh, after a full day of research in total, I realized the problem..

First of all, the code above is not supposed to work actually. The `oauth` parameters have to go into the query string apparently. That's how all WooCommerce client APIs do it:

```
post(endpoint, data_params, params = null) {
  const method = 'POST'

  const oauth_params = this._getOAuth().authorize({
    url: 'https://boundlessmaps.gis-ops.com' + '/wp-json/wc/v3' + endpoint + WooCommerceAPI._normalizeQueryString(params),
    method: method
  })

  return this._request.post(endpoint, data_params, {
    params: oauth_params
  })
}
```

So that should work in theory, **but still doesn't**. The OPTIONS preflight fails. Now that's apparently indeed a server-side problem. [Basically WooCommerce has a limitation](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/27aa0664df927f610e42f9a694eb452cee49e245/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php#L311-L320) which I didn't fully understand tbh. The way around is to avoid a preflight, which apparently is possible if you avoid `Content-Type: application/json` header and a `body`. Using `axios`, you just put all parameters in the query string and leave the `body` and `headers` empty. This wouldn't work on all servers, but it does with WooCommerce luckily.

References:

- https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/14987#issuecomment-300581467
- https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/15395#issuecomment-305471553

The working solution is:

```
post(endpoint, data_params) {
  const method = 'POST'

  const oauth_params = this._getOAuth().authorize({
    url: 'https://boundlessmaps.gis-ops.com' + '/wp-json/wc/v3' + endpoint + WooCommerceAPI._normalizeQueryString(data_params),
    method: method
  })

  return this._request.post(endpoint, null, {
    params: oauth_params
  })
}
```

Happy hacking;)